# How to hide and show a sprite in P5?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to hide and, after a while (a delay), show the sprite at the starting point of the game. Tried to use p5 play library but it didn't work (conflicts with collide's lib). Is there any way to hide and show the sprite with a delay between actions?
I will leave the game link https://editor.p5js.org/miasensei/sketches/5jhlxGIYg

Comment: You need to add the code to the question. A link to an off-site resource is not sufficient. Links to external resources tend to break and the resource may no longer be available in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In each frame, assuming you redraw the background or clear the canvas, every drawing instruction you call from the `draw()` function  will be displayed, and only the drawing instructions you call from the `draw()` function will be displayed. So if you want there to be a delay between when a sprite is not and is displayed, you simply need to have some variable controlling whether the drawing instructions are called or not. Here is a simple example (your linked code is way to complex to share a simple solution):

```js
let disableDisplayUntil;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function mouseClicked() {
  // hide the circle for 3 seconds
  disableDisplayUntil = millis() + 3000;
}

function draw() {
  background(100);
  // Only display the circle if the delay has not been set,
  // or the current time is greater that the specified delay
  // time
  if (!disableDisplayUntil || millis() > disableDisplayUntil) {
    circle(mouseX, mouseY, 20);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.js"></script>
```